# Google Calendar synchronization spec

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a question regarding "Add Calendar By URL" function in Google Calendar:

1. How often it is updated (most sources I've found says 24h per day). Does `caladress.ics?noCache` workaround still works?
2. How it is updated? If I have a large calendar (e.g 2008 - 2016) and add a single event, does Calendar reupload the whole calendar or check for diff? If check for diff, is there any limitations?
3. Is there any limit to how long events could be? E.g is it possible to set 5 year event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. How often it is updated (most sources I've found says 24h per day).Does caladress.ics?noCache workaround still works?**

Based from the Google [thread](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1), updates may take a few hours for the new information to be parsed and viewable by your users.

> Note: It might take up to 12 hours for changes to show in your Google Calendar.

You can use `no-cache` to indicate that the returned response cannot be used to satisfy a subsequent request to the same URL without first checking with the server if the response has changed. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) and [example](https://github.com/johntron/superagent-no-cache).

**2. How it is updated? If I have a large calendar (e.g 2008 - 2016) and add a single event, does Calendar reupload the whole calendar or check for diff? If check for diff,is there any limitations?**

Calendar is updated based on how you will implement the "incremental synchronization" of calendar data. It can be *Initial full sync* or *Incremental sync*.

[Initial full sync](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#initial_full_sync) is performed once at the very beginning in order to fully synchronize the client’s state with the server’s state.  You can optionally restrict the list request using request parameters if you only want to synchronize a specific subset of resources.

While [Incremental sync](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#incremental_sync) allows you to retrieve all the resources that have been modified since the last sync request. You need to perform a list request with your most recent sync token specified in the `syncToken` field. Keep in mind that the result will always contain deleted entries, so that the clients get the chance to remove them from storage.

**3. Is there any limit to how long events could be? E.g is it possible to set 5 year event?**

For the limitation, the Google Calendar API has a courtesy limit of 1,000,000 queries per day. You can see the calendar usage limits [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en). It is possible to set an event as long as you haven't reached the limit for the number of events you can create.